# How can I clear/flush the L2 cache (and the TLB) of a GPU?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, cpu-cache, tlb

I have a discrete NVIDIA GPU (say, Kepler or Maxwell). I want to clear my L2 cache before some kernel is scheduled, so as not to taint my test results.

I could do something like allocate a large slab of memory and read sequentially a lot of it that's someplace far away, and that will probably work. But I'd much rather do something simpler...

Notes:

- I'm also interested in how to do this in OpenCL, albeit less so.
- PTX inlining is acceptable (but I'd rather write proper code).

Comment: You could do cudaMemset for that allocated memory, this should work as well. I cannot think of any simpler way.

Comment: @MaximMilakov: I don't want to change the values in the memory, that would defeat my whole purpose. I want to write something into memory, clear the caches, then launch some kernel accessing that memory.

Comment: Your solution is "to allocate a large slab of memory and read sequentially". I am saying that if you allocated that large slab just for the sake of clearing L2 cache then you could cudaMemset this large slab, this should also do the job.

Comment: @MaximMilakov: And do we know for certain thus cudaMemset will not bypass the cache somehow?

Comment: All access to DRAM is through L2 cache

Comment: The solution described by @MaximMilakov is also used in Nvidia's own [nvbench](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvbench/blob/1a13a2e724b8aa8aee27649ac6878babb63862a6/nvbench/detail/l2flush.cuh) (linking to a certain commit for consistency but for now its the same on main).

Comment: If you only want to do it for one specific device architecture, which you have available, why not profile with Nsight Compute? You can check, whether memory allocated before cudaMemset is still cached by reading it and checking the cache hit rate.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>So, to recap the comments by @MaximMilakov and @paleonix:</sub>

1. Allocate a large slab of memory (at least as large as L2; perhaps larger)?
2. Perform a `cudaMemset()` on this large slab.
3. Supposedly, the memory you will have written to with the memset operation will be cached in L2 - clearing whatever else was in L2 previously.

... and this approach is used in NVIDIA's own [nvbench](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvbench/) utility.

caveat: It's a bit strange that this works, since the reads and writes with `cudaMemset()` shouldn't necessarily result in L2 caching.